# Using XDomainRequest Object in HTA application

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, cross-domain, hta, xdomainrequest

I have an HTA aplication, which gets some data using through ajax call. I satrted to use XMLHttpRequest for this. This method was giving me the desired result, but it was coming with a pop up before sending a request as shown [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/04/22/ie-security-prompt-page-accessing-cross-domain-information-not-under-its-control.aspx).

So as suggeted in the previous link, i tried using [XDomainRequest Object](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx). But this is giving me error on xhr.open() method call; as i think the protocol for HTA application is file:; while XDomainRequest only supports ttp: and https: protocol.

Is there any workaround where i can get data using a cross domain call without intimating user on IE 8.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear where the requested file is located at.

When it's accessible via HTTP/HTTPS(no matter which domain) you may use [WinHTTPRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/aa383989%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)